# What is the meaning of "when I was but a boy" from the sentence given down below?

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction

"The canny, lovable old Scotsman carelessly tossed it into my mind, **when I was but a boy**."

Comment: Only a boy, just a boy.

Comment: I was a boy and just a boy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of the word "but" there is this:
[American Heritage Dictionary "but"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=but)
"adv. 1. Merely; just; only: *hopes that lasted but a moment*."

So, the idea was put to him when he was only a boy.